# Converting class based component into functional based component and using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I am learning ReactJs and I am trying to implement below react classs based component into functional component but I am having difficulties in it. When I implement this into functional component it does not updates the webpage.

I have imported DISHES an object from where I gets the data. I am trying to set state using functional component

Below I have attached some code which I tried to use to set state

```
   class Main extends Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    dishes: DISHES,
                    selectedDish: null,
                };
            }
        
            onDishSelect(dishId) {
                this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId });
            }
        
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Navbar dark color="primary">
                            <NavbarBrand href="./" className="mx-5">
                                Ristorante De Confusion
                            </NavbarBrand>
                        </Navbar>
                        <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={(dishId) => this.onDishSelect(dishId)} />
                        <Dishdetail
                            dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === this.state.selectedDish)[0]}
                        />
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
        
        export default Main;
```

This is I am trying to convert

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from "reactstrap";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import Dishdetail from "./Dishdetail";
import { DISHES } from "../shared/dishes";

function Main() {
    const [dishes] = useState({ DISHES });
    const [selectedDish, updatedDish] = useState(null);

    function onDishSelect(dishId) {
        return updatedDish((selectedDish) => ({
            ...selectedDish,
            selectedDish: dishId,
        }));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar dark color="primary">
                <NavbarBrand href="./" className="mx-5">
                    Ristorante De Confusion
                </NavbarBrand>
            </Navbar>
            <Menu dishes={dishes} onClick={(dishId) => onDishSelect(dishId)} />
            <Dishdetail dish={dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === selectedDish)[0]} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: Can you edit to include the complete React function implementation you are trying to use? See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what minimal e.g. you have given it would be as so, edit the props as required and used ...

```
function Main(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    selectedDish: null,
    dishes: DISHES, // it's not clear from where it is referred `props.Dishes` if from props
  });

  function onDishSelect(dishId) {
    setState({ ...state, selectedDish: dishId });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar dark color="primary">
        <NavbarBrand href="./" className="mx-5">
          Ristorante De Confusion
        </NavbarBrand>
      </Navbar>
      <Menu dishes={state.dishes} onClick={(dishId) => onDishSelect(dishId)} />
      <Dishdetail
        dish={state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === state.selectedDish)[0]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. DISHES is coming from dishes.js file where I have created an object containing all the id, author name, comments, description sort of things. I am importing that as DISHES and trying to use dishes. So in that case  I can use dishes directly. I have also come to understand that if I am not altering state then I can use that directly. But again thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

It seems the issue is in the `onDishSelect` handler, it is nesting the dish id in a nested property.

```
const [selectedDish, updatedDish] = useState(null);

function onDishSelect(dishId) {
  return updatedDish((selectedDish) => ({
    ...selectedDish,
    selectedDish: dishId, // <-- nested
  }));
}
```

And doesn't correctly access into the nested property when rendering to filter the `dishes` array.

```
state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === state.selectedDish)[0]
```

## Solution

Just set the `selectedDish` to the passed `dishId` value.

```
const [selectedDish, updatedDish] = useState(null);

function onDishSelect(dishId) {
  updatedDish(dishId);
}
```

Instead of `Array.prototypt.filter` which returns an array that you need to access the 0th element of, use `Array.prototype.find` to find and return the matching element object.

```
state.dishes.find((dish) => dish.id === state.selectedDish)
```

There's also no need to store the `DISHES` array in local state, just reference it directly in the component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from "reactstrap";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import Dishdetail from "./Dishdetail";
import { DISHES } from "../shared/dishes";

function Main() {
  const [selectedDish, updatedDish] = useState(null);

  function onDishSelect(dishId) {
    updatedDish(dishId);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar dark color="primary">
        <NavbarBrand href="./" className="mx-5">
          Ristorante De Confusion
        </NavbarBrand>
      </Navbar>
      <Menu
        dishes={DISHES}
        onClick={(dishId) => onDishSelect(dishId)}
      />
      <Dishdetail dish={DISHES.find((dish) => dish.id === selectedDish)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't fully understand the `useState` hook. It essentially provides you with 2 variables:

```
The state variable itself
A set method for the state variable
```

Here is how you'd actually set up your state variables:

```
const [dishes, setDishes] = useState(DISHES)
const [selectedDish, setSelectedDish] = useState(null)

const selectADish = dishId => setSelectedDish(dishId)
```

As for accessing state, you no longer write

```
this.state.dishes
```

rather you just write `dishes` as that is the variable within your function component scope.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `const [dishes] = useState({DISHES});` There's no requirement to destrcture the state updater function.

Comment: True, but why store it in state if you are not going to use the set function?

Comment: Why indeed. I don't disagree that it's unnecessary.

Comment: OP is obviously just starting to learn react. IMHO this question can be very easily answered by spending 5 minutes reading docs.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to unpack here:

- It doesn't render on screen because you need to return the JSX
- When instantiating the state dishes you don't need to wrap the data in an object
- Do you need dishes-state? Currently, you are not altering the state, so you could just use DISHES

With those changes, here's what the code could look like:

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
  import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from "reactstrap";
  import Menu from "./Menu";
  import Dishdetail from "./Dishdetail";
  import { DISHES } from "../shared/dishes";

  function Main() {
    const [selectedDish, setSelectedDish] = useState(null);
    return (
      <div>
          <Navbar dark color="primary">
              <NavbarBrand href="./" className="mx-5">
                  Ristorante De Confusion
              </NavbarBrand>
          </Navbar>
          <Menu dishes={DISHES} onClick={dishId => setSelectedDish(dishId)} />
          <Dishdetail
              dish={DISHES.filter(dish => dish.id === selectedDish)[0]}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default Main;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. It is working as expected. Also u helped me to understand that if I am not altering state then I can use that directly.